# Python Pandas - read date column as string

Tags: python, excel, pandas, date

I have some data in an excel file and I read it using pandas read_excel method.
However I want to read the entire data in all columns as strings including the date column.

The problem is that I want to leave the date column in its original format as string. For example, I have '31.01.2017' in the excel and it is formatted as date and I want to have '31.01.2017' in my data frame.

I thought using dytpes parameter of read_excel with dtype=str was the correct approach. But pandas then reads the date column as datetime and then converts it to string. So at the end I always have '2017-01-31 00:00:00' in my data frame.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

The behavior of pandas makes sense:

- If the excel-format of your date column is text, pandas will read the
  dates as strings by default.
- If the excel-format of your date column is date, pandas will read the dates as dates.

However, you point out that in the Excelfile the date column is formatted as a date. If that's the case, there is no string in your Excelfile to begin with. The underlying data of the date column is stored as a float. The string you are seeing is not the actual data. You can't read something as a raw string if it isn't a string.

Some more info: https://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/formatting.html

But let's say, for some reason, you want Python to display the same format as Excel, but in string form, without looking in the Excel.

First you'd have to find the format:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook('data.xlsx')
ws = wb.worksheets[0]
print(ws.cell(1,5).number_format)  # look at the cell you are interested in

> '[$]dd/mm/yyyy;@'
```

and then convert is to something the strftime function understands. 
https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/strftime#format-code

```
form = form[3:-2]
form = form.replace('dd','%d')
form = form.replace('mm','%m')
form = form.replace('yyyy','%Y')
print(form)
> '%d/%m/%Y'
```

And apply it

```
df.loc[:,"date_field"].apply(lambda x: x.strftime(form))

> 0     01/02/2018
1     02/02/2018
2     03/02/2018
3     04/02/2018
4     05/02/2018
```

However, if you're working with multiple Excel date-formats you'd have to make a strf-time mapping for each of them.

Probably there will be more practical ways of doing this, like receiving the data in csv format or just keeping the dates in excel's text format in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

As you are trying to keep the date column in the initial type, the following code may help you. In the first row we insert to the variable "cols" all the columns except the date column, and then in the following two lines we just change the type of the rest columns:

```
cols=[i for i in df.columns if i not in ["Date_column"]]

for col in cols:
    df[col]=df[col].astype('category')
```

Hope it helps! :-)

Comment: But you are iterating over the dataframe after(!) reading the excel file. And the problem occures during the reading of the file. So your dataframe has the dates stored in it and they have already lost the initial format

Comment: And what is actually the point of changing the type of all other columns to categorical?

Answer (score 0):

```
df['date_column'] = df['date_column'].dt.strftime('%d.%m.%Y')
```

Comment: The problem is that after reading the data I don't know what the original date format was

Comment: I don't know what the hesitation would be in not just looking at the date format by opening the file and then using `strftime`, seems inefficient. You've got a couple of options at the point. If the parameter `converters={'Date': str}` doesn't work, then convert to csv before reading in excel.

Comment: But how can I look up what the format is? Do you mean opening the file with some other package or do I miss something...

Comment: Open it with excel?

Comment: Ah ok. Unfortunately, I want to do the whole thing automatically