# Reading in spreadsheet with Python Pandas that does not parse the dates

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to read in a spreadsheet with Python Pandas that does not parse the dates.

I have tried to use a lot of the methods mentioned in a previous posting, but none work for me.

This is the code (spreadsheet is just the name of the file):

```
columns = pd.ExcelFile(spreadsheet).parse(tab).columns

converters = {column: str for column in columns}

df1 = pd.read_excel(spreadsheet, sheet_name=tab, parse_dates=False, dtype=converters)
```

I realize that there is a previous posting on this, but none of the suggested fixes work for me. I've even included them above, but I am still getting parsed dates in the text files that I am creating out of the spreadsheet.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you post an example date format that you are not able to parse?

Comment: Maybe something like this: [Python Pandas - read date column as string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46693095/python-pandas-read-date-column-as-string)

Comment: The dates all appear on the spreadsheet I am reading in the same way: MM/DD/YYYY (for example, 04/14/2000). But Pandas parses some as dates and others as strings. I want to disable the parse as dates facility.